# send mail to a grouped destination mail address using python

Tags: python, email

I need to send mail to some grouped destination mail address and also to indivuduals mail address. Then individual mail address can receive the mail but all mail inside the group can not.

How can I fix this issue please?

Below is my code:

```
def send_mail(df_table):
    #get destination mail address
    address_book = ['me.@example.mg','group1.@example.mg','group2.@example.mg']
    
    msg = MIMEMultipart()    
    sender ="noreply.@example.mg"
    subject ="My subject"
    df_table = df_table.to_html()
    body = df_table

    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = ','.join(address_book)
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))
    text=msg.as_string()
    s = smtplib.SMTP('mymail.example.mg:25')
    s.sendmail(sender,address_book, text)
    s.quit()
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: All mail address inside the grouped mail can not receive the mail.

Comment: Is the grouped mail declared on the mail server?

Comment: Yes, when I send manualy mail to the grouped address, it's ok. But in my code not

Comment: Hmm..., many mailers have *local* groups. If you are sure that the group is known to the server, you should ask the admins whether restrictions are enforced. For example not all sender addresses could use some groups.

Comment: Yess, exactly, our Network administrator had just said that there are restrictions. Thanko you very much

Comment: Then feel free to self ask your question. It might help future readers.